# Select Files From Folder Depending on Name Convention

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, fileinfo

I receive a bunch of XML files in a folder.

I want to keep checking for files that have the following naming convention:

```
sr-{first_id}-{second_id}-matchresults.xml
```

To parse as soon as I receive one.

For example:

```
sr-40-24-standings.xml
sr-40-24-results.xml
sr-40-24-j7844-matchresults.xml
```

I should select that one : `sr-40-24-j7844-matchresults.xml`

What comes after this that helps me select Files depending on their naming convention from a ASP Web Service?

```
 Dim files As IO.FileInfo() = FolderName.GetFiles("*.xml")
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Classic ASP, can you remove the tag, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private bool IsValid(string value)
    {
        string regexString = "^sr-([a-z0-9]+)-([a-z0-9-]+)-matchresults.xml";
        return Regex.IsMatch(value, regexString);
    }
```

This method will give you the files with the specified format (sr-{first_id}-{second_id}-matchresults.xml).
Note: your Ids can contain alphanumeric characters also "-" symbol. if you don't want that symbol in id, then code will look like,

```
string regexString = "^sr-([a-z0-9]+)-([a-z0-9]+)-matchresults.xml";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"^sr-.............$");
```

And then apply a "filter" on Directoy.GetFiles to retrieve only the files matching this pattern:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("path to files", "*.xml").Where(path => pattern.IsMatch(path)).ToList();
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I liked the filter technique however cannot you just obtain the same effect with Directory.GetFiles("path to files", "sr-*.xml")? Besides the regular expression matches only filenames of the same size.

Comment: Hi, all the files will start with sr, but its the rest of the structure that matters. please check the edit

Comment: You are right it is also possible to filter directly in the `Directory.GetFiles("path to files", "sr-*-matchresult.xml")` or even `Directory.GetFiles("path to files", "sr-*-*-matchresult.xml")`. If more control is needed (for example to make sure the ID is structured in a certain way), then regex is probably the way to go.

Comment: @sblandin: Isn't that the point?  The filenames are in a specific format.

Comment: @paul the original post didn't give too detailed information about the format. I just tought that with a * you can match any file name lengths